# AWS SDK for Java - Add ProgressListener to TransferManager.copy

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, sdk

Has somebody managed to use a `ProgressListener` when using `copy` method of the `TransferManager`?

I didn't find anything related on the Internet and the only hint that this might not work is in this blog post:
[Amazon S3 TransferManager](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/amazon-s3-transfermanager/)

> One of the more commonly used options is the ability to attach a
>   progress listener to your uploads and downloads, which can run custom
>   code at different points in the transfer’s lifecycle.

To describe what happened to me ... the ProgressListener wasn't receiving any events, even if the transfer was done.

Comment: Do you have problem only when using the `copy` method? You should paste here some code, a minimal example of what didn't work.